# sun microsystems logo xscreensaver?

Tags: solaris, xscreensaver

I stumbled on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364760) question today asking for a [Bob screensaver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLbe67PprBSpqM_-HU49fmIS8ncApw4i08&v=LuEC3EONzjc). I can recall that and it reminded me of days past. I also remember a screen saver, either life or snake - i can't remember which or perhaps it was both, that rendered the Sun microsystems logo.

I wonder if that's still available somewhere ?

(Those of a certain age may also remember the Motif [kit cat version](http://codefromabove.com/2014/05/catclock)  of `xclock` which I [found again](https://github.com/BarkyTheDog/catclock) on GitHub.)

Comment: Thanks for the tips!  But sadly, *all* the links are to the same video - the Bob screensaver...

Comment: You can also find the source code for lots of versions of `xscreensaver` at **archive.org**.  Just type in the URL to the xscreensaver's download-page in the WayBackMachine.  Not all versions are there, but lots of them are - all the way back to about 2006 (prior to that, they don't seem to have gotten the tar.gz-archives).

Comment: I fixed the links. I don't know how that happened!

Comment: You can always get the Sun BSOD screen.  Just install xscreensaver-screensaver-bsod then go in and set the settings to show Sun.  That one is kinda fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xlock` included in Solaris used the Sun logo for the Game of Life mode.
The sources to it were published during the OpenSolaris days, though I think we had to replace the logo with a generic image for trademark reasons.  They're currently posted under https://github.com/oracle/solaris-xorg/tree/master/open-src/app/xlock/sun-src (or `git clone https://github.com/oracle/solaris-xorg.git ; cd open-src/app/xlock`).

This screenshot is from `xlock -mode life` running on Solaris 10:

[image: Screenshot of Solaris lock screen displaying Game of Life with Sun logo for cells]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a link handy, but I seem to recall stumbling upon an "Open" OpenWindows distro that might have what you're looking for.  However, since the source was probably closed and for SPARC, you might only find it if someone liked it and rewrote it for their platform of choice?

Comment: you're probably right that it's closed-source. I have some solaris media from some time ago, I might take a look at that if I get some time... Oh, I just did a quick search and found [openlook on sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openlook)

Comment: The CDE (Common Desktop Environment) is also on sourceforge and another possibility.